# way to change audio accent iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, openal

I am in search for a framework or **third party API to change the accent of volume**, as Talking Tomcat is changing volumes Pitch, same way I need to change the accent.

If changing accent is not feasible then any way to set pitch which can represent something similar to any accent like Indian or Arabic or British or American.

Thanks to All

Answer (score 0):

As a 3rd party library i'd recommend [Dirac3](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html). There are some sample projects included with the library.

You can also download a sample app that uses Dirac from [Making that Talking App!](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app) by Hsiao Wei Chen. This app also uses Cocos2D underneath (which is not really needed) but serves the purpose anyway.